# What is the red dot in the review queues?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, design

A red dot is showing under my review queue, what is it?

[image]

Comment: This question should be moved to https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jon Ericson's post in Meta Stack Exchange answers it:

[How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly)

> With the rollout of the new top bar, you’ve probably noticed the new review indicator:
>
> ...
>
> So the idea is that when you see the indicator light up, it’s a reminder that there are reviews to be done if you haven’t looked recently.
>
> ...
>
> Each queue may be in one of three states:
>
> No dot (empty queue)
> Grey dot (at least one but fewer than N review tasks)
> Red dot (N or more review tasks)

---

**Update**: the logic for lighting up the review queue icon became more complex, and is still subject to change, so refer to the main post for follow ups.

As a side note from me is that most times I get that red dot in my review icon, I click on it but I am already late for the party (no posts; I think it is due to caching).